# remove all my gmail contacts that not delivered

Tags: gmail

i sent numbers of emails for all my gmail contacts and my friends

this is google message that i recieved for some of them that old or not exist yet:

> The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
>   double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary
>   spaces.

after sending, most of them delivered and some of them not delivered. i received not-delivered email notifications like that , from google

i know:

> For a number of reasons, recipients’ email servers can reject emails
>   that you send. Gmail returns a message reflecting the response
>   provided by the recipient’s server.

how can i remove all of that not delivered contacts or old emails contacts from my contact list